# Join from inversed side

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

given the two following intities:

```
<?php
    /**
     * User
     * @ORM\Entity()
     */
    class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable, EncoderAwareInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var Vip
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Vip", mappedBy="user", fetch="EAGER")
         */
        protected $vip;

        // …

<?php
    /**
     * Vip
     * @ORM\Entity()
     */
    class Vip
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\id @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="vip", fetch="EAGER")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
         */
        protected $user;

        // …
```

---

**SHORT :**
How can I do this SQL in DQL given above entities:
`SELECT u.firstName, v.foo FROM User join Vip v ON v.user_id = u.id`

In other words how can I retrieve 10 first users ( with their VIP infos if it exists), using DQL `join` in such a way that only one SQL query will be generated by Doctrine. Is that possible ?

---

**Long story:**
The owning side is the `Vip` entity because it holds the reference/foreign key to a User underneath in the database.

I am trying to retrieve all `User` with their `Vip` datas.
Using the *knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle*, I first set up a simple query:

`$dql   = "SELECT u, p FROM AppBundle:User u;`

In spite of enforcing the fetch attribute as « EAGER », `Vip` infos where not part of the initial query. As a consequence, calling getter `getVip()` on each iteration from inside the twig `for in` loop like

```
{% for user in pagination %}
    {% if user.getVip() %}
        <span class="label label-warning">V.I.P</span>
    {% endif %}
{{% endfor %}}
```

.. caused a query to be issued on each iteration !

The Symfony dev bar shows 6 queries:

[image: paginator OneToOne relationship queries issued by Doctrine]

DQL documentation and says that one can use JOIN keyword. So my query became:
`$dql   = "SELECT u, v FROM AppBundle:User u JOIN u.vip v`;

But now I get this error:

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, null
>   given

**Here I'm stuck, wondering how I could fetch `Vip` datas (or null) along with `User` datas, in a single query.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one may add associated entities to the SELECT statement.
But more precisely, one should only add relations that are really involved in the expected result , in other words, entities fetched as "EAGER".

I realized that the `vip` entity had another relation (oneToMany with a `vehicule` entity). I just want to retrieve users with their vip metas. Adding another JOIN to the query would just bring more datas since I would not use vehicules anyway (and issue extra work behind the scenes).

-> So I simply **change**d ***the fetch attribute from "EAGER" to "LAZY"*** in the `vip` OneToMany declaration.

### To conclude:

Ask yourself **«what are involved intities ?»**, should it be part 
of the result (do you simply need those infos).

**if NO**, you might turn fetch attribute to "[EXTRA_]LAZY" in the relation declaration like

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vehicule", mappedBy="vip", fetch="LAZY", …)
 */

protected $vehicules;
```

**if YES** you will have to select those entities in your query.

Using DQL:
`SELECT u, v`**, w** `FROM AppBundle:User u LEFT JOIN u.vip v` **LEFT JOIN v.vehicules w**

Using queryBuilder:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository(User::class);
$users = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->addSelect('v')
    ->join('u.vip', 'v')
    ->addSelect('w')
    ->join('v.vehicules', 'w')
    // …
```

Answer (score 1):

> In other words how can I retrieve 10 first users ( with their VIP
>   infos if it exists), using DQL join in such a way that only one SQL
>   query will be generated by Doctrine. Is that possible ?

You should initialize all related entities using select clause to avoid additional queries when accessing to the related objects.

```
$repository = $em->getRepository(User::class);

$users = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->addSelect('v') // Initialize Vip's
        ->join('u.vip', 'v')
        ->getQuery()
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: @John_Smith thank you for your time. Actually, the DQL available right after "getQuery()" is the same as the one I emphasized in my Question. But you helped me figuring what was going wrong `;)`